# How to reference Access query defs from Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a need to change the SQL of a query saved in Access from Excel and it must use late binding.

Specifically I'm building SQL strings in Excel VBA featuring a number of parameters provided by the user in Excel and querying the database via an ADODB connection. I have constructed core queries in the database which do most of the work so I can keep my SQL strings and the amount of data returned light on the Excel end.

Mostly this works fine but some of those core queries rely on other queries nested several levels deep, and some of the parameters I need to supply are around data in those parent queries. So, I'm thinking I need to temporarily amend the SQL of those parent queries before running my main code (unless anyone has another idea?). I know how to change the SQL for a queryDef in Access, but not how to get to the queryDefs from Excel.

So TL:DR - how can I get a handle on the queryDefs in an Access accdb from Excel?

Thanks.

Comment: If you use DAO you can access the `CurrentDB.QueryDefs` collection.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your suggestion using the DBEngine class and can now access the querydefs. I can't find much on late binding DBEngine and DAO though - CreateObject doesn't work - any ideas?

Comment: You just need the right class: `CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120").OpenDatabase(...).QueryDefs`

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a late bound example

```
Dim db As Object
Dim qdef as Object
Set db = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120").OpenDatabase("path to db")
set qdef = db.QueryDefs("query name")
```

Comment: @sujoy it was tested by me before posting and confirmed as working by the OP.

Comment: Then it must be incomplete, cause its not working when we paste it as is.

Comment: "not working" really doesn't give a lot to go on. I suggest you start your own question if you have a problem - you can always reference this one.